# VS2017 Solution Template Structure

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-templates

I have generated a VS (multi-) project template which I am having trouble trying to control the **base** hierarchy structure when it is used.

The template source folder/full solution has the following projects

```
MyTemplate.UI
MyTemplate.BusinessLogic
MyTemplate.DataModels
MyTemplate.Helpers
MyTemplate.Interfaces
MyTemplate.Services.APIConnector
MyTemplate.Services.AuthProvider_AAD
```

The `.vstemplate` file is

```
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
    <TemplateData>
        <Name>IoC Template</Name>
        <Description>Template with IoC/project separation</Description>
        <Icon>Icon.ico</Icon>
        <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    </TemplateData>
    <TemplateContent>
        <ProjectCollection>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.UI" CopyParameters="true">
                    MyTemplate.UI\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.BusinessLogic" CopyParameters="true">
                    MyTemplate.BusinessLogic\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.DataModels" CopyParameters="true">
                    MyTemplate.DataModels\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Helpers" CopyParameters="true">
                    MyTemplate.Helpers\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Interfaces" CopyParameters="true">
                    MyTemplate.Interfaces\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <SolutionFolder Name="$safeprojectname$.Services" CopyParameters="true">
                <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.APIConnector" CopyParameters="true">
                    MyTemplate.Services.APIConnector\MyTemplate.vstemplate
                </ProjectTemplateLink>
                <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.AuthProvider_AAD" CopyParameters="true">
                    MyTemplate.Services.AuthProvider_AAD\MyTemplate.vstemplate
                </ProjectTemplateLink>
            </SolutionFolder>
        </ProjectCollection>
    </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Now, when then solution/project is created, everything deploys as expected, however, it always seems to insert an additional folder level from the base folder...

So, lets say I want to create a project call `WidgetProject`, in VS2017, `File-> New -> Project`, select the template and set the following

```
Name = WidgetProject
Location = C:\WorkProjects
Solution name = WidgetProject
Create directory for solution = ticked
```

What this then generates as a folder structure is

```
C:\MyProjects\WidgetProject\WidgetProject.sln
                            WidgetProject\WidgetProject.UI
                            WidgetProject\WidgetProject.BusinessLogic
                            WidgetProject\WidgetProject.BusinessLogic
                            WidgetProject\WidgetProject.DataModels
                            WidgetProject\WidgetProject.Helpers
                            WidgetProject\WidgetProject.Interfaces
                            WidgetProject\WidgetProject.Services\APIConnector
                            WidgetProject\WidgetProject.Services\AuthProvider_AAD
```

All of the project folders are an extra layer deep... I want to put them at the same folder level as the `.sln` file.

I am sure it is just a simple setting in the `.vstemplate` file, but i just cant figure it out.

TYIA

Comment: The thing is that VS only allow to create a project template, which at the creation is placed in a folder in the solution. I doubt you can do something for that. Or if you found I would be glad to know.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunate but when you create a new project based on your template, there is a setting "Place solution and project in the same directory" in the dialog screen.
As it looks like there is no way to control this from the template definition.
All you can do: you can write a comment into your description node of project (or project group) definition, that you are preferring that specific setting for your solution...